# Activate Airpush account for tunisian Citezen

Tags: android, airpush

How to validate Airpush Account when we are a Tunisian citezen ?

because I created ann account, and my informations dose not validate yet.

Answer (score 0):

To activate airpush account

- download w8ben form and insert the following informations 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0sm6iqev33qz7b6/model%20w8ben.pdf
- send an email to support@airpush.com attached

  ```
   - A copie of your passport / Identity card etc..
   - The Tunsian tax guide available on : http://www.claytonmckervey.com/attach/worldwide-tax-guide-tunisia.pdf
  ```

Good luck